# Gitlab workflow without a project maintainer

Tags: gitlab

So I've looked around a little bit and I'm not sure if gitlab is the right server for us. It basically means you need a gate keeper of sorts.

So our situation looks like this, we have no single person that will be merging from a developer branch to master. We want all code that goes into master to be reviewed first and automatically merged into master if its a fast-forward merge.

Its easy to protect the master branch by protecting the branch and making everyone a developer but then no one can merge to master... or at least that is what I gathered from reading some of the docs.

Is it possible to set up permissions that any one can merge to master so long as there was a pull request and everything reviewed. Automating that will come later.

Is there another server that you would recommend that could do something like this. I know gerrit works more like this but has a functional but not overly intuitive gui.

Comment: Probably a subset of this to force the reviews: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6530328-disallow-merge-of-own-merge-requests-disable-self

Comment: This is probably not possible. I recommend you make a small, very well defined feature request and post it on the feature tracker for this kind of question: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general